# How to apply .input-validation-error apply to kendo Editor in MVC4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am working with Kendo Editor in my MVC4 application and achieved Model based validation with

```
 $("form").data("validator").settings.ignore = ":hidden:not(#Text)";
 $.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: [] });
```

Kendo build it's editor around TextArea and mark it as hidden field. Now validation is working but .input-validation-error class is not being added to it if validation fails. Can anyone suggest how i can do so.

Answer (score 0):

The point is that the input-validation-error class is applied to the original hidden field...not to the editor. You have to intercept the valisation fail event and you must add manually this class to the editor.

There are two ways to intercept validation events. The simpler one is by specifying a custom showErrors function in the options you pass to the setDefaults method. The validation plugin documentation explains how to do this.

The other way is to redefine the element and form methods of the validator object prototype...it is not difficult but requires you have a deeper knowledge of the validation plugin.

I suggest to use the first approach and to put a breakpoint in your showErrors function, so that you may familiarize with the format of the arguments passed to it. Dont forget to call the default showErrors function after you add your customizations.

Dont forget that the validation errors must be also cleared. Now if the plugin will not clear your custom errors (maybe...because they are not attached to an input field) you are forced to override the element and form methods also because the showErrors function is not called if there are no errors while the above methods are called in any case so you can pot there your clearing code....

My advice is to concentrate in showing the error at the beginning, and after you adquire familiarity with the way the validation plugin works, to concentrate on clearing your custom errors if it is necessary (maybe they are cleared automatically by the plugin...not sure about how the plugin clears its erros)